# How do I write a number as a string to an Excel file?

Tags: excel, matlab

I have a cell array in MATLAB which contains numeric data stored as a string. I would like to maintain this string format when I export the file. However, when I use `xlswrite`, Excel automatically converts these to `double` values. Does anyone know how to prevent this?

Here's an example of what I have written:

```
    C = {'123'};
    xlswrite('example.xls', C);
```

When I check the file, "123" is stored as a number.  Specifically, I can perform arithmetic operations on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Insert a single quotation in front of each number before writing to file. The single quotation at the beginning informs Excel that you wish to input a string regardless of its contents:

```
C = {'''123'};
xlswrite('example.xls', C);
```

You need to use two `'` characters to symbolize a single quote to ensure MATLAB doesn't ambiguously think that you're trying to start a string... so to be sure we're on the same page:

```
C =  {'''123');
      |||   |
      abb   a
```

`a` denotes the starting and ending of the string and `b` denotes the declaration of a single quotation.

Comment: @user32882 - No problem. Good luck!